# Silverlight and ClearType: just won't do

Tags: silverlight, fonts, cleartype

I am desperately trying to improve the visuals of my Silverlight application, but it won't work.

No matter what I do, **I always get grayscale antialiasing**, while I would like to get the standard Windows 7 full-color ClearType antialiasing. If I zoom in, this is clearly visible.

I am currently doing it by setting the following properties:

```
TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Fixed"
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
```

To check that they are applied, I tried to set the TextHintingMode to Animated, and it gets a lot worse. Same thing if I set TextRenderingMode to Aliased: I see that it changes too, so I am setting them in the right place. Unfortunately the final effect is ugly.

How can I turn ClearType on?? Using Silverlight 5.

Thanks!!

Comment: silverlight fonts are famously bad. There are some tricks to make is no quick so terrible. Google for 'ugly silverlight fonts'